# AutoMapper, the reverse map not working for embedded objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, mapping, automapper, .net-5

I have a class `Affaire`, containing `Secteur`s, containing associated `Emplacement`s, and corresponding DTO objects to transform.  I use `AutoMapper` for that.

```
public class Affaire 
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }

public class Emplacement
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }

public class EmplacementDTO
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public string AffaireNom { get; set; }
```

The Emplacements are grouped in `Secteur`, having as well its `Affaire`

```
public class Secteur
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
    public IList<Emplacement> Emplacements { get; set; } = new List<Emplacement>();
```

When I map from `Emplacement` to a `EmplacementDTO` I don't want to include `Affaire`, only `AffaireId`:

```
CreateMap<Emplacement, EmplacementDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireId, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Id))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireNom, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Nom))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForPath(bo => bo.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(dto => (Affaire)null)); // <<<< HERE
```

This configuration does not seem to work when Emplacement is embedded in a container `SecteurDTO`, however, for the container itself, the configurartion seem to work (its `Affaire` is set to null):

```
CreateMap<Secteur, SecteurDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireId, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Id))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireNom, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Nom))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForPath(bo => bo.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(dto => (Affaire)null))
```

[image]

related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67648810/961631)

Comment: Hi @Serge, I could not reproduce the issue, please share your whole model design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working demo in my project:

Model:

```
public class Affaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public IList<Emplacement> Emplacements { get; set; } = new List<Emplacement>();
}
public class Emplacement
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
}

public class Secteur
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
    public IList<Emplacement> Emplacements { get; set; } = new List<Emplacement>();
}
```

DTO:

```
public class EmplacementDTO
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public string AffaireNom { get; set; }
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
}
public class SecteurDTO
{
    public int AffaireId { get; set; }
    public string AffaireNom { get; set; }
    public Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
    public IList<EmplacementDTO> Emplacements { get; set; }
}
```

Profile:

```
public class YourProfile : Profile
{

    public YourProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Emplacement, EmplacementDTO>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireId, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Id))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireNom, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Nom))
                .ReverseMap()
                .ForPath(bo => bo.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(dto => (Affaire)null));

        CreateMap<Secteur, SecteurDTO>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireId, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Id))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireNom, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Affaire.Nom))
                .ReverseMap()
                .ForPath(bo => bo.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(dto => (Affaire)null));
    }

}
```

Backend testing code:

```
public List<EmployeeModel> Index(List<SecteurDTO> dto)
{
    dto = new List<SecteurDTO>()
    {
        new SecteurDTO(){
            AffaireId=1,
            AffaireNom="aaa",
            Emplacements = new List<EmplacementDTO>()
            {
                new EmplacementDTO(){AffaireId=1,Affaire=new Affaire(){Id=1,Nom="aa"}}
            },
            Affaire=new Affaire(){
                Id=1,
                Nom="aaa",
                Emplacements=new List<Emplacement>()
                {
                    new Emplacement(){AffaireId=1,Affaire=new Affaire(){Id=1,Nom="aa"}}
                }
            }
        }
    };
    var bo= new List<Secteur>() { };

    var mapper = _mapper.Map(dto, bo);

    //...
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: not sure what happens, I removed some EF object loading, do not load Affaire at all, only the Ids... so probably the automapper works well, or not, I can't test, but if you sample is working is OK. is important however to see the state of object before (with affaire not empty), and after (with Affaire empty)